# Laravel Non authenticated users needed to be able to store data and images

Tags: php, database, laravel, session, cookies

I am developing a REST API in Laravel and need to find a solution for the following problem. The application has a card builder section, in which users can create up to 18 cards. Each card has a front and back image, logo image, and original image the user selected for the background.

All are great for the logged users but the card builder section is for guest users as well.

Simply, the card builder has 18 steps and on each step, the backend has to store 4 images and JSON with config data.

I have two possible solutions for now. Use a Visitors table to store data for non-authenticated users. This way I can transfer data to the user's tables if they register. Or use cache for storing the information.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "keep track" here. If you only need to track it within a session for that user, you can store it in a session variable (just create some random temp token in the session and store that with the data). If you want to keep track between sessions for that user, you can use a cookie. If you want to track it for all users to see, or even if they clear cookies, then you need some kind of authentication.

Comment: Will do. Basically, user has 18 steps in which each card is created. On each step, on the backend I have to store back, front, original and logo image. So each step sends a request and those images are saved along with some config data for the images. Keeping track means that images are saved along with json config.

Comment: Then it should work if you generate a random token (string) which you store in a session when they start and use that to know who made each request on each step. It would basically work just as if they logged in and you stored the use id in a session.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sounds good to me. What about the config json? Is it better to have a table to store this data or use cache? Or maybe keep it on the client side and store just images in the backend, like in a folder with the token name?